# Unit vector in a form of rectangular components

Tags: vector-analysis

I've met this difficult question while answering some problems related to vector analysis. The question goes like this:

"Find in rectangular components the unit vector which is in the direction of $\bar E$ at $P(1,2,-2)$ if $\bar E = x^2 + y^2 + z^2$.

$$\frac{x}{\sqrt{y^2 + z^2}}a_x + \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + z^2}}a_y + \frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}a_x"$$

I have no idea where to start, so how do you answer this question?

Comment: $\bar E=x^2+y^2+z^2$ is a number, so what is its ''direction''?

Comment: What do you mean by "vector used"?

Comment: @EmilioNovati and @T L Davis Honestly, I don't know. I was preparing for a licensure exams and when I'm reviewing, I would see these kind of questions. Kinda scratched by itchless head......ahahahahah!  Sometimes, we just regurgitate facts to pass. How do you interpret that above question?